# Compare Data from Two Columns and Match Figures Against Each Other

Tags: excel, duplicates, formula

I'm trying to compare figures from Sales data where Data set 1 (column A) comes in before the data set 2 (column B). Generally this data lines up chronologically, but it does not always and never row by row when pasted side by side. This is because column A is just transaction totals and column B contains the transactions split into product totals. For example:

Bob buys a $2 widget, $3 ball and a $5 stick. The data entry as it appears to me would be Column A $10 and Column B $2, $3 & $5.

These transactions don't occur often however and I need to isolate them from the overall data set and any figures that don't have matches. Most of the data generally has one to one transactions. For example:

Fred buys $5 widget. Column A $5 Column B $5.

Highlighting the matching 1 for 1 figures cells and leaving the odds fill blank would be optimal.

I have tried a few formulas and am getting nearly 90% success rate, which is close, but so frustrating. Basically just need a formula that will format the cells that have a 1 for 1 unique match in both columns and leave the ones that don't have a buddy highlighted. Also has to be done chronologically (so something in say column A row 112 can't match column b row 56).

So if anyone can help me out that'd be amazing. My only other option is analysing 10,000+ lines manually. Save me internet!

ps - sorry for the formatting, couldn't post lined up because it thinks I'm coding.

Comment: You will need more than 2 columns to solve this. You will need to provide a key along with the amount - the key could be timestamp, or it could be the name (e.g. Bill). You would need this in both sets of data, so A = Bill, B = 5, C = Bill D = 5. If you can do this, (and your key data would have to be unique), then you can solve this properly. I am sure I or someone else could provide a solution if you have this information. The problem is that there is currently no way to prevent matching inappropriate repeats of the same value. Even in your question you mention something about dates.

Comment: There are dates but 80% of the time they don't line up. The data in column A always comes in first (its website data) and then column b is the website interfacing with our system. There can be a delay sometime, but 80% of the time it's correct. 

If using the date can eliminate a good chunk that will still help. I have two date data sets. One is just by day, the other is timed to seconds which has a delay sometimes when recording to B data.

Comment: The data is sorted 99.9% chronologically if that helps. So a formula that just grabbed the next match down the line within lets say 20 rows should work.

Comment: It seems we need to use vba. but firstly provide a sample.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1getZ1qbDFaC5XeHmSiWRYCesirr09quBGqctORJOqUQ/edit?usp=sharing

I don't have a copy nor can share a copy of the data itself (confidential, lose your job ect ect). But I have recreated exactly what it looks like, just image like 30,000 more rows.

Answer (score 0):

For Column E

> =INDEX($B$2:$B$100,MATCH($E2,$B$2:$B$100,0))

```
     A          B       C           D    E
   2 Date       WData   Date        DB   Data   
   3 2/10/2018  1000    2/10/2018   1000 1000
   4 2/10/2018  800     2/10/2018   450  #N/A
   5 2/10/2018  900     2/10/2018   350  #N/A
   6 2/10/2018  850     2/10/2018   900  900
   7 2/10/2018  680     2/10/2018   850  850
   8 2/10/2018  790     2/10/2018   680  680
   9 2/10/2018  645     2/10/2018   790  790
```

Comment: I will edit this post when I will have more answers: What does mean D3 and D4 and B3? How do you want to be interpreted the E3 and E4?

Comment: B3 would be the total amount that the website receives and D3 & 4 would be the individual product that's make up that transaction. I gave the example using Bob. The website data (B3) would show $10 and D3,4 & 5 would show $2, $3 & $5. 
An error message is fine like it shows the #N/A. Just need something that sticks out to grab my attention as I'm scrolling.

Comment: You can create a conditional formatting for column E to add a bg color for rows with #N/A than? This is enough for you?

Comment: Is enough to see the errors for me. Your performed the same as the other ones I've tried, nearly perfect. Two issues though. One the same figure will appear multiple times throughout the columns and they have to be matched off against each other. So $100 in column A can't match both of the column B $100 if there are two entries. It needs go against one of them and leave the other B entry as unmatched. 
Secondly, because of the product split in column B the data gets further out of alignment. So first 100 rows data in line, 100 -200  B data is lower down by about 30 rows and so on.